# Assigning element of an array to a variable without square brackets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know this is probably a fairly simple problem but it has really stumped me. I want to assign each element of an array to its own variable, without the square brackets being carried over.

This is basically what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1],[1],[3]])
a = X[0]
print(a)
```

This outputs `[1]`
How do get it to just output `1`

If I try the above with:

```
a = float(X[0])
```

The console spits out an angry message telling me not to use float, despite the code running fine.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `X.shape` is (3,1). a 2d array with 3 rows and 1 column.  `X[0]` is one row , with shape (1,).  That's why it displays with [].  `a=X[0,0]` indexes one element of that 2d array.  Read more of the beginners docs for numpy.

Comment: The duplicate is for a nested list, your example is a 2d array,  Do you understand the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array of list instead of array of numbers. Each number is inside a list. Just remove the square brackets you have put for each number in X, that would solve this issue.

```
X = np.array([1,1,3])
```

Now your output would be just numbers

You can see the difference when you print X:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1,1,3])
print(X)
X = np.array([[1],[1],[3]])
print(X)
```

Output:

```
[1 1 3]
[[1]
 [1]
 [3]]
```